# Why can't my popup.js communicate with my background.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have...

**manifest.json**:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
```

**popup.js**:

```
    console.log("before send message");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"},
        function(reply) {
          console.log("before print reply");
          console.log(reply);
          console.log("after print reply");
        });            
      console.log("after send message");
```

**background.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log("before send response");
      sendResponse({say: goodbye});      
      console.log("after send response");
  }
);
```

Why, then, does my console look like this?

```
before send message
after send message
before print reply
undefined
after print reply
```

It looks like I'm not touching the insides of my listener described in `background.js`.

Comment: In general are you interested in exchanging only one message ? have you thought of establishing long lived connections using ports ? @steven_noble

Comment: at this stage i'm happy to send one-off messages as required

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The extension that I was using to automatically reload my extension had not added the background.js page. I added it later by vising the extensions page and hitting command-R. All works fine now.

Comment: I found it much better to manually force refreshing extensions during development. I once relied on some extension and had to pull my hair few times before realising it was only a refresh issue :) @steven_noble

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly, you're sending an undefined `goodbye` variable instead of `"goodbye"` string.